# complex integral of conjugate on polygonal curve

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals

I need help with solving the following question:

Let $G$ be an open, bounded and connected set which its boundary is a polygonal chain. Calculate:

$$\int_\gamma \overline z \, dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the boundary of $G$.

Any ideas or hints?

**EDIT:** Ok so I know that $\int_\gamma \overline z \, dz = 2iArea(G)$ but I don't know how to prove it..

Answer (score 0):

You can write $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \overline z \, dz=\displaystyle\int_\gamma (x-iy) \, (dx+idy)=\displaystyle\int_\gamma xdx +ydy+i\displaystyle\int_\gamma -ydx +xdy$ and apply the Green's theorem.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't learnt yet Green's theorem.Any other way?

Comment: That is a pity. With the Green's theorem we quickly get $\int_\gamma \overline z \, dz=2iS$ ($S$ polygon's area).

Comment: Well do you know other ways?

Comment: @chakachaka Do you know the vertices of the polygon? If so you could just compute the contour integrals along each component segment connecting the vertices.

Comment: @user170231 No, I don't know the vertices.

Comment: @chakachaka : Believe me, if you haven't covered the Green's theorem you'll not be able to provide a "decent" solution.  :)